# Customized web gui for asterisk

Tags: php, web, asterisk, pbx

May I ask what options I have to create a customized web UI for Asterisk using PHP or any other web platform. The app involves performing tasks like managing CDR, managing Users, managing interconnections between external servers, managing IVR, managing DID etc all from the web interface.

I learnt about PHPAGI from another thread. Will that be helpful in what I am trying to achieve? If no, what other options do I have.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have full control on asterisk.

It is free,opensource.

If you want do it yourself, start from this book http://www.asteriskdocs.org/

However in most cases it is recomended contact asterisk developer/freelancer. just becuase GUI created by non-asterisks professional have very hi chance to be not scalable and buggy.

Also you can look into freepbx.org code or a2billing.org code.

Main thing you have to REALY know before proccess with your own interface is asterisk extensions.